# How to find the coordinates of a point w.r.t another point on an image using OpenCV

Tags: image-processing, opencv, image-recognition, hough-transform

Today I wrote a program for detecting circles using Hough Transform using OpenCV in C.
The program inputs 3 images, each image contains a fixed small circle and a big circle with variable position. The program then recognizes both the circles and marks the centres of both the circles. Now what I want to do is that in the output image the (x,y) coordinates of the centre of the bigger circle should be displayed with respect to the centre of the fixed smaller circle . Here's the code for 'circle.cpp'

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    IplImage* img;
    int n=3;
    char input[21],output[21];    

    for(int l=1;l<=n;l++)
    {     
      sprintf(input,"Frame%d.jpg",l);  // Inputs Images

      if(  (img=cvLoadImage(input))!= 0)
    {
        IplImage* gray = cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(img), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1 );
        IplImage* canny=cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img),IPL_DEPTH_8U,1);
        IplImage* rgbcanny=cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img),IPL_DEPTH_8U,3);
        CvMemStorage* storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);
        cvCvtColor( img, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY );
        cvSmooth( gray, gray, CV_GAUSSIAN, 9, 9 ); // smooth it, otherwise a lot of false circles may be detected
        cvCanny(gray,canny,50,100,3);

        CvSeq* circles = cvHoughCircles( canny, storage, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 2, gray->height/4, 200, 100 );
        int i;
        cvCvtColor(canny,rgbcanny,CV_GRAY2BGR);
        for( i = 0; i < circles->total; i++ )
        {
             float* p = (float*)cvGetSeqElem( circles, i );
             cvCircle( rgbcanny, cvPoint(cvRound(p[0]),cvRound(p[1])), 3, CV_RGB(0,255,0), -1, 8, 0 );
             cvCircle( rgbcanny, cvPoint(cvRound(p[0]),cvRound(p[1])), cvRound(p[2]), CV_RGB(255,0,0), 3, 8, 0 );
        }
        cvNamedWindow( "circles", 1 );
        cvShowImage( "circles", rgbcanny );

        //Displays Output images
        sprintf(output,"circle%d.jpg",l);   
        cvSaveImage(output,rgbcanny);    
        cvWaitKey(0);
    }
}
    return 0;
}
```

And here are the input and output images:
[image] [image] [image]
[image] [image] [image]

Please suggest what changes should I make in the code to display the desired (x,y)coordinates. Thanx a lot :)

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do. Do you want to display the X,Y coordinates of the center of the big circles? Is that all?

Comment: Yes, I want to display the (x,y) coordinates of the center of the big circle w.r.t. the center of the small circle taken as origin(0,0) in the output image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you show the image, use [cvPutText](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/core_drawing_functions.html#puttext) to add the desired text. The parameters of this function are self-explaining. The font should be initialized using [cvInitFont](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/core_drawing_functions.html#initfont).

When you calculate the relative coordinates, keep in mind that in OpenCV, the coordinate system is like this

```
-----> x
|
|
v
y
```

just in case you are interested in showing the relative coordinates in a system in which the axes point in another direction.

You should check that the Hough transform has detected exactly two circles. If so, all the data you need is in the `circles` variable. If (xa,ya) are the coordinates of the bigger circle and (xb,yb) the coordinates of the smaller one, the relative coordinates are (xa-xb,ya-yb).

Comment: Thanx for the reply but before displaying the desired text using 'cvPutText' how can I find the coordinates of both the centers, which function should I use to do this ?

Comment: See the paragraph I added to my answer.

Comment: Thanx a lot mate for the invaluable 'hints'
marked it as the answer :)

Comment: but any idea how should I detect that only 2 circles are recognized ?

Comment: circles->total should be the number of detected circles.