# Strange coordinate appears after finding moments of circles

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, coordinates

i am using open CV and C++. I used find Contours and moments to display the center coordinates of circles in an image. However,there is this strange coordinate which appears in between the good ones. It is [-2147483648,-2147483648]. Does anybody know what it means? 
thanks

Comment: If you haven't done so yet, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn what a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) is.

Comment: Sounds like an overflow, but without any code to look at it's near impossible to say for certain.

Comment: Try using `long` or `long long` instead of integer.  The values may be an error code.

Comment: yes!!the problem is with the type I use..instead of using int I used long long but this time the weird coordinate is [0,0] in between the correct coordinates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chances that this reason occurs could due to the integer type used. Also known as an integer overflow.

This occurs when an arithmetic operation attempts to create a numeric value that is too large for the available storage space which you declared.

However, there may be other reasons as well. From what I noticed, the values are kind of big. May I ask what is the size of the image that you trying to implement the contours and moments on? Cuz I have done something similar myself, and the values are way too big.

If the size of the image you are processing is a not of humongous size(like really really big), then there might be something wrong with the code. Please edit the question to include the code, so that all the stackoverflow people can help you.

This are some links of how to find the centre of a circle, hope you find it useful. I used this links when I was doing a similar program back then.

[How to find the coordinates of a point w.r.t another point on an image using OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5795921/how-to-find-the-coordinates-of-a-point-w-r-t-another-point-on-an-image-using-ope)

http://lfhck.com/question/278176/python-and-opencv-how-do-i-detect-all-filledcirclesround-objects-in-an-image

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it was not about the type that i used but it was the image quality which had problems. I had to blur that part so that it does not detect that color there.